# Google's hosted dojox.gfx

Tags: dojo

I'm using the following html to load dojo from Google's hosting.

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("dojo", "1.1.1");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dojox.gfx");
...
```

This errors out on the requre line with an error like dojox.gfx is undefined. Is there a way to make this work, or does Google not support the dojox extensions?

Alternatively, is there another common host I can use for standard dojo releases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differently from when you reference the .js files directly from the <script> tag (note that google js api also supports this, see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/#dojo)), google.load is not synchronous. This means that when your code reach google.load, it will not wait for dojo to be fully loaded to keep parsing; it will go straight to your dojo.require line, and it will fail there because the **dojo** object will be undefined.

The solution (if you don't want to use use the direct <script> tag), is to enclose all your code that references dojo in a **start** function, and set it will as a callback, by doing:

```
google.load("dojo", "1.1.1", {callback: start});

function start() {
    dojo.require("dojox.gfx");
    ...
}
```

or

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(start);
google.load("dojo", "1.1.1");

function start() {
    dojo.require("dojox.gfx");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that google becomes the namespace for your imported libraries. Try: `google.dojo.require`.

Oh! And as pointed out below, don't forget to use google.setOnLoadCallback instead of calling your function directly.

Answer (score 0):

A better question is - why would you want to? If you are developing on your localhost then just use a relative path, if you're developing on an internet facing server - stick the dojo files on that.

Also - make sure you're not falling foul of the [same origin policy](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Using an external version makes it easier to share single file prototypes with other users for now. Besides, Google sold me with their http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation

Answer (score 0):

dojox is practically unmaintained, and will be taken out from dojo-2. There are major problems with most widgets in dojox, there is only a few good.

IMHO dojo should be self-hosted, because there are always things what you need to overwrite - for example, you need some fix in this dojox.gfx.